# Can't figure out why my change(...) event handler isn't working in this scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, event-handling

The relevant piece of HTML is like

```
<tbody id="results">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
            <a href="c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\myproj\Assets/someorg-somecategory-somepic.png" class="hidden">c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\myproj\Assets/someorg-somecategory-somepic.png</a>
        </td>
        <td>someorg</td>
        <td>somecategory</td>
        <td>somepic.png</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My intent is for the `a` elements next to the `input` elements to be visible or hidden depending on whether or not the `input` is checked.

Seems like it should be simple enough:

```
$('#results input').change(function() {
    console.log("ok, this function got called.");
    this.siblings('a').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

inside a `$(function() { ... });`

But, that's not working. Nothing is being printed to the console when I test by checking or unchecking the element. Any idea why this might be? Need me to post any more code?

Comment: Try `$('#results').find('input')`, and also try `.click(` instead of `.change(`.

Comment: Is your `tbody` wrapped in a `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `id` to the checkbox or `class`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
```

And use `$(this)` not `this`

```
$(this).siblings('a').toggleClass('hidden');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/omnzocqq/

**update**

According to my idea, you forget to put the `table` wrap to `tbody`. But if you add your `table` wrapper element and edit `this` to `$(this)`, your code works.

So you don't need to add a `class` or `id` to your `checkbox`.

http://jsfiddle.net/omnzocqq/3/

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/omnzocqq/1/)

Comment: Can you explain why I would need to add an ID or class? Why won't the JQuery selector `$('#results input')` target the element? Also, using an ID or class won't work for my specific program because my table will normally have multiple rows and I need an event handler attaches to each input and refers to itself.

Comment: Ok, the reason why you add a class or id is to make easy to add an event handler to the input. But when i [make another test](http://jsfiddle.net/omnzocqq/3/), you didn't add the table element. Now, your code work if you add the table element to wrap the tbody! :). here a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/omnzocqq/3/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because within the handler `this` is a DOMElement. You need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object to be able to call jQuery methods on it:

```
$('#results input').change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('a').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/558cb3fa/)

Comment: That's true, however OP said  "Nothing is being printed to the console" so the function doesn't seem to be triggered at all.